# Android Custom keyboard with horizontal scrollable

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view, horizontal-scrolling

I have developed a custom keyboard with my custom buttons. 
I have added all my buttons using

```
<Row>
<Key ....... />
</Row>
```

This format.

All goes well but now I am out of row addition. As there are already four rows added that already captures half screen. 
So now I want to add one more layout that act as view pager. Which has more rows in another page.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can use the <ScrollView></ScrollView> layout to make the keyboard View scroll horizontally and more buttons can be added in each row, Still not as the ViewPager but maybe will work.
Also you mentioned the ViewPager, so did you tried it ? and what happened?